# Github connection doesn't show up when selecting github release on azure

Tags: azure, github

Via pipeline => edit => add task there's an option for adding a "Github release" which requires a GitHub connection (OAuth or PAT). I've added both an OAuth and a PAT with `repo, user, admin:repo_hook`, but none of the connections show up. I've ticket the box "Allow all pipelines to use this service connection" on the pipeline policies on the service connections. Not sure what else I could do to make any of the service connectors show up with the github releases.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: wait some time until Azure syncs.